# Executing event and scrape using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new in selenium and I was looking forward to execute a `click()`  button that expands a table, and after that I was looking forward to scrape the content of the expanded table.

This is what I tried:

```
url = 'https://www.telegraph.co.uk/markets-hub/assets/shares/'
phantomjs_path = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path,service_args=['--load-images=no'])
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tmg-show-more']")

html_source = driver.page_source
element.click()
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,"html5lib")
tables=soup.find('table',class_="table-static kurser-table")
link=pd.read_html(str(tables),flavor='html5lib',thousands='.',decimal=',',header=0)



print(link)
```

The current output is as it follows:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated",
"request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-
Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:58447","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},
"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\": \":wdc:1556893378248\", \"sessionId\": \"f223cb80-6dae-11e9-b00b-4bb158952171\"}",
"url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"",
"userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/f223cb80-6dae-11e9-b00b-4bb158952171/element/:wdc:1556893378248/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: What is the result of your code?

Comment: You want to click on `All button` and scrap the data right ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to scroll down to let the selenium web driver knows where the element is actually present.

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://www.telegraph.co.uk/markets-hub/assets/shares/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.section-box.kurser-table-container')))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ng-click='stocksShowMore()']")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

element.click()
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ElementNotVisibleException` means you are trying to click the element before it is visible.

Also, you are getting the page source before clicking the button. You need to get the source after clicking and loading the new data.

Try the following code before getting the page source.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tmg-show-more']")))
element.click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(element))
```

To use the `WebDriverWait` you need to import these

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```